# What are the real world, production grade cases for domain events (understood as events within same bounded context & process)?

Tags: domain-driven-design

If we have a bounded context with lets say 2 aggregates where `aggregate1` publishes `event1` and `aggregate2` wants to react to it, we have 1 ways of doing it:

1. in process raising `event1` > `aggregate2` reacting to it
2. publish `event1` to message bus and have some separate process pick it up & invoke `aggregate2` method(s)

regardless of being within the same bounded context, if we want to make sure we don't lose `event1` (application crashes between `aggregate1` is saved, and `aggregate2` is saved in reaction to `event1`, e.g.) i have a hard time finding examples of when would option 1 be better than option 2 (beyond maybe validation)?

i must be missing something but at this point of my knowledge, it seems like a pure theoretical concept to me without some real world value in terms of reliability and ability to maintain correct state.

of course that publishing a message and having separate process listen/react to it might seem like an overkill but is there any practical use of domain events that are not persisted somewhere (even within local DB which gets polled in which case i'd call that a primitive message bus)?

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a real world application of domain events within a bounded
> context and process?

**Requirements:**

- User can create categories.
- Category names must be unique.
- User can rename categories.

(Category will have a number of other properties unrelated to naming).

**DDD Concepts:**

- A Category aggregate should be responsible for its own internal invariants, but cannot know the details about other Category aggregates.

*How are you going to ensure that the Category Name for the current Category is globally unique without the Category having access to all other categories?*

Answer: Domain Events

**DomainEvent**

```
public CategoryRenamed : DomainEvent
{
    public Category Category { get; }

    internal CategoryRenamed(Category category)
    {
        this.Category = category;
    }
}
```

**DomainEventHandler**

```
public CategoryRenamedHandler : IDomainEventHandler<CategoryRenamed>
{
    public CategoryRenamedHandler(CategoryRenamed domainEvent)
    {
        string proposedName = domainEvent.Category.Name;

        // query database to ensure that proposedName is not already in use
        if (inUse)
            throw new Exception($"Name {proposedName} already in use." ;
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    List<DomainEvent> _domainEvents = new List<DomainEvent>();

    protected AddDomainEvent(DomainEvent domainEvent)
    {
        _domainEvents.Add(domainEvent);
    }

    public List<DomainEvent> DomainEvents => _domainEvents;
}
```

**Category**

```
public class Category : Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Category(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        SetName(name);
    }

    public Rename(string name)
    {
        SetName(name);
    }

    void SetName(string name)
    {
        // Local Invariants
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(name))
            throw new Exception("Invalid name");

        Name = name;

        // Add a domain event for the infrastructure to process
        AddDomainEvent(new CategoryRenamed(this));
    }
}
```

**Command**

```
public class AddCategoryCommand
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**CommandHandler**

```
public class CommandHandler : ICommandHandler<AddCategoryCommand>
{
    readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;

    public CommandHandler(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
    {
        _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }

    public void HandleCommand(AndCategoryCommand command)
    {
        Category newCategory = new(command.Id, command.Name);

        // Check for domain events before committing to repository
        DomainEventDispatcher.DispatchEvents(newCategory.DomainEvents);
        // Dispatcher will find the CategoryRenamed event and send 'in-process'
        // to CategoryRenamedHandler
        // If name was is in use an error will be thrown by the handler (see above)

        _categoryRepository.Add(newCategory);
    }
}
```

**Outcome**

Your Category aggregate has enforced its own local invariants and the domain command and domainevent handling infrastructure has been leveraged to ensure uniqueness of name across all categories.

Comment: oh, that was enlightening. yes, its definitely elegant solution, thanks  a bunch! PS. i will accept an answer and if you could, please just list 2-3 more possible use cases. thanks!

Comment: In summary a Domain Event is useful when you want to validate beyond to scope of the aggregate being maintained or want additional side effects beyond the scope of the aggregate being maintained.  E.g. your design might have concluded that you want an "OrderItem" to be an aggregate, but you also want the "Order" total to be updated whenever an OrderItem is added / amended / deleted.  You can use the same pattern here.  OrderItem adds an event that its created / amended / deleted and an EventHandler can load the Order aggregate into the Unit of Work and update total within the same transaction.